# MySQL BETWEEN clause returns nothing if only today is available. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that gets data from a range of dates. While debugging it, I've run into this peculiar issue in which:

**if the table contains only records with today's date, nothing shows.**

HOWEVER

**if I add records from yesterday, then yesterday and today shows.**

What am I missing?

MySQL Query:

```
/*
SELECT GROUP BY UTL_ACTION | SUM UTL_DURATION
*/
SELECT USER_ID,
       UTL_ACTION,
       SUM(UTL_DURATION) AS UTL_DURATION_TOTAL       
  FROM (

SELECT A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID,
       A.CLIENT_ID,
       A.PROJECT_ID,
       A.USER_ID,
       A.UTL_DTSTAMP,
       /* DATE_FORMAT(A.UTL_DTSTAMP,'%H:%i:%s') AS UTL_DTSTAMP, */
       A.UTL_LATITUDE,
       A.UTL_LONGITUDE,
       A.UTL_EVENT,
       A.UTL_ACTION,
       /* DURATION in seconds  */
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, A.UTL_DTSTAMP, B.UTL_DTSTAMP) AS UTL_DURATION
FROM   tbl_user_time_log A
       INNER JOIN tbl_user_time_log B
               ON B.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID = ( A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID + 1 )
WHERE  A.USER_ID = '465605'
       /* Between current pay period Start date and Current pay period end date */
       /* First day of the week is Monday.*/
       AND ( A.UTL_DTSTAMP BETWEEN '2018-01-22' AND '2018-01-28' )
       /* Filter out Clock Out. */
       AND A.UTL_EVENT <> 'CLOCK OUT'

ORDER  BY A.PK_USER_TIME_LOG_ID ASC

) AS tbl_derived_1

GROUP BY UTL_ACTION ASC;
```

Table...

[image: sample1]

Desired Result...

[image: sample2]

Comment: What are you missing?  Sample data, desired results, and a query for one thing.  Someone with your reputation should know how to write a question.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will see to it that I am more thorough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to use `between` with date/time types.  Although for SQL Server and not MySQL, a [blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) by Aaron Bertrand does a good job explaining why.

You can probably fix your logic by doing:

```
(A.UTL_DTSTAMP >= '2018-01-22' AND
 A.UTL_DTSTAMP < '2018-01-29'
)
```

Note that the second comparison uses `<`, not `<=` and the comparand is one day more.

Comment: No way... so simple... you are brilliant. Just out of curiosity, <= seems to work. Is it not good practice or...? Actually... it doesn't.

Comment: @Vini . . . `<=` is *bad practice*.  It would include midnight on that day and no other times.  It is highly unlikely that is the intention of the logic.